# targeting id on a loop to toggleClass with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make it so when a user presses a button, an element inside the button changes class. I managed to do that when I have a clear id for button.

```
<button id="buttonId"><i class="class1"></i></button>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#buttonId").click(function(){
            $(this).find('i').toggleClass('class2').toggleClass('class1');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now I need to create a sequence of buttons, and for that I've set the id like this:

```
{% for i in X %}
<button id="{{i.id}}"><i class="class1"></i></button>
{% endfor %}
```

However I don't know how I can reference i.id inside the function. The example below didn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("{{i.id}}").click(function(){
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('class2').toggleClass('class1');
    });
});
```

How do I find the id?

Comment: You don't. Give all the buttons the same class instead `$(".buttonClass").on('click', function(){ $(this).find('i').toggleClass('class2').toggleClass('class1'); });`

Comment: Please read the docs about .toggleClass. It accepts a space separated string of all the classes to toggle, so no need to chain methods. And btw toggling two classes is often sign of bad design. You only need to toggle one class. From a default state to a special state.

Comment: @mplungjan That worked, thanks! I don't really know much about jQuery, so sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'm trying out Fonts Awesome, so I am just testing to see what I can do, I'm just trying to learn. I don't think I can do as you suggested as I'm using `<i class="far fa-star">` and I want to change it to `<i class="fas fa-star">` but if I can do it all in one toggleClass I'd like to know how bc I'm really just starting with Jquery.